# Possibility of reusing nested select value in other nested selects

Tags: sql-server

Is it possible to create a reusable nested select statement in TSQL? Something like this?

```sql
Select(
   Select1(reusable)
   Select2(where Select1)
   Select3(where Select1)
   Select4(where Select1)
)
```

or do I need to rewrite the same select statement to get the value I need to use in other selects in every lower statement? I tried to use it as below but I get always errors.

```sql
(SELECT TOP (1) LOCATION    FROM Address AS d   
WHERE(RECID = trans.Address) ) as loc,

(SELECT TOP (1) CITY WHERE
(loc = other.recid)) as CITY
```

Comment: See: [WITH common_table_expression (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16).

Comment: Are LOCATION and CITY on the same Address table? If so, the closest thing to what you're thinking is sub-queries. Although, I imagine you could solve your problem with a GROUP BY as well.

SELECT TOP (1) LOCATION, (SELECT TOP(1) CITY FROM Address WHERE recid = loc.recid) AS CITY FROM Address AS loc WHERE RECID = trans.Address;

Comment: I have 2 tables. One transaction where is recid to address table. The problem is that I need for my report only good data( no mistakes or empty fields) the address table contains different versions based of time. So based on transaction recid I need to find the location id and after find and check the latest valid address. Ex. A address edited 2 times is 3 rows in address table I need to get the latest address for its id. If a transaction refer the the first two that are wrong or incomplete I need to pick the last version of it.